# Reducing queue length from application pool in IIS when a load balancer is used

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, load-balancing, load-testing

I have a testing environment where web application deployed. However, it seems there are two servers in which this particular web application is deployed. These two servers are under a load balancer. I would like to use one server for load testing to reproduce a particular issue, by reducing number of request from app pool. How can I do this?As this is on load balancer and I want to use (temporarily use ) one server only to reproduce issue, what setting I need to change in load balancer? Basically, how to reduce the **queue** **length** when application is deployed on two servers with a load balancer?

Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: What load balancer do you use? Simply remove one server out of the cluster, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. However, reducing queue length should be done from web server App pool? Or, is there something needs to be done in load balancer itself(after removal of one server out of the cluster).